# How can I remove a lockset latch assembly that's stuck latched?

Tags: lock, doorknob

My latch is stuck. I couldn't turn the handle, even unlocked, so I removed the handles. Now I've got direct access to the latch assembly, and I can't get the unlatching part to move (to the right, in the photo). How can I get this door open? I can't normally remove the latch assembly without opening the door.

[image: deadbolt and lockset with handles removed]

Comment: Some combination of wiggling and force. Try putting pressure against the door in case the latch is binding against the strike. Note that only the inner part of the latch mechanism (the square ends inside the D opening) move to pull the latch: back.

Comment: The latch is not binding against the strike. It's rather free, with a good 2-3mm of wiggle on the door (into the weatherstripping on the other side of the doorjamb).
I am aware that only the small bits inside the top right and bottom right corners of the (| opening are supposed to move to the right to unlatch it.

Comment: Can't advise you further without getting my hands on the beast,  I'm afraid.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove the pins from the hinges. You should then be able to pivot the door out of the opening. Once the door is removed you can remove the screws that hold in the strike bolt.

Comment: I absolutely already knew this. I feel dumb now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The upper deadbolt is still locked in the picture.
Once it is unlocked, simply either use a screwdriver to pull the striker inwards, or use the old credit card trick we all learned in middle school to push the latch in from the outside.

Comment: It is the kind of latch with the little extra half-cylinder latch bit that stops the credit card trick from working.

Comment: That just makes it harder. *Locks keep honest people out.*

Comment: @Mazura the way that that makes it harder is by forcing you to use a different method...